# Sed on Mac not recognizing regular expressions

Tags: regex, macos, sed, terminal, grep

In terminal, I am attempting to clean up some .txt files so they can be imported into another program. Only literal search/replaces seem to be working. I cannot get regular expression searches to work.

If I attempt a search and replace with a literal string, it works:

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/Title Page// {} +;`

(remove the words "Title Page" from every text file)

But if I am attempting even the most basic of regular expressions, it does not work:

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/\n\nDOWN/\\n<DOWN\>/ {} +;`

(In every text file, reformat any word "DOWN" that follows double return: remove extra newline and put word in brackets: "\n")

This does not work. The only thing at all "regular expression" about this is looking for the newline.

I must be doing something incorrectly.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update: part 2**

John1024's answer helped me out a lot for one aspect.

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' '/^$/{N; s/\n[0-9]+/\n/;}' {} +;`

Now I am having trouble getting other types of regular expressions to respond properly. The example above, I wish to remove all numbers that appear at the beginning of a line.

Argh! What am I missing?

Comment: It is not that direct to replace a multiline in `sed`: [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/40596)

Comment: it can work if you place whole file in pattern space, like ':loop; N; $! bloop; ...'

Comment: The first command you show should not work.  You show `-exec sed -i '' s/Title Page// {} +` but because of the space between Title and Page, there is an incomplete substitute command followed by a file name `Page//`.  You need to use quotes (single or double) for it to work: `-exec sed -i '' 's/Title Page//' {} +`.  (The semicolon in the question is redundant but otherwise harmless.)

Comment: Your update is probably best asked as a new question.  Show more precisely the input data you are planning to edit in all its glory (the DOWN editing as well as the number editing). If you continue using `sed`, you may have to revise your 'other commands' to recognize that the numbers at the start of a line appear some way through the pattern space (after other lines).  Example input and desired output is sensible here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, sed handles only one line at a time.  When a line is read into sed's pattern space the newline character is removed.

I see that you want to look for an empty line followed by `DOWN` and, when found, remove the empty and change the text to `<DOWN>`.  That can be done.  Consider this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
some
thing
DOWN

DOWN
other
```

Try:

```
$ sed '/^$/{N; s/\nDOWN/<DOWN>/;}' file
some
thing
DOWN
<DOWN>
other
```

#### How it works

- `/^$/`

  This looks for empty lines.  The commands in braces which follow are executed only on empty lines.
- `{N; s/\nDOWN/<DOWN>/;}`

  The `N` command reads the next line into the pattern space, separated from the current line by a newline character.

  If the pattern space matches an empty line followed by `DOWN`, the substitution command, `s/\nDOWN/<DOWN>/`, removes the newline and replaces the `DOWN` with `<DOWN>`.

#### Special Case: DOS/Windows Files

If a file has DOS/Windows line endings, `\r\n`, sed will only remove the `\n` when the line is read in.  The `\r` will remain.  When dealing with these files, the presence of that character, if unanticipated, may lead to surprising results.