# Using sed to clean up text files using regular expressions

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Continuation of a previous question
[Sed on Mac not recognizing regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655001/sed-on-mac-not-recognizing-regular-expressions)

I am editing and cleaning up multiple text files, preparing them to be input in another piece of software. I have not been able to get Sed to process actual regular expressions:

I know these are not correct, but the closest I can come to describing the code I am interested in. Please compare the two lines of code to the input and output.

Any help greatly appreciated.

1. Get rid of all numbers at beginning of line:

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' '/^$/{N; s/\n[0-9]+/\n/;}' {} +
   ```
2. Format file:

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' '/^$/{N; s/([^\n]+)\nACROSS\n/<ACROSS PUZZLE>\n<TITLE>\n\1\n<AUTHOR>\n\n<COPYRIGHT>\n\n<SIZE>\n15x15\n<GRID>\n<ACROSS>\n/;}' {} +
   ```
3. Any time there are two or more underscores, replace with only three

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' '/^$/{N; s/\_\_+/\_\_\_/;}' {} +
   ```
4. Any time there are ellipsis with spaces between the dots, remove the spaces:

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' '/^$/{N; s/\. \. \.+/\.\.\./;}' {} +
   ```

Input:

```
nxd-12345678 Serial number of file
Title of File
ACROSS
1 __ fast
2 IRS-form experts
10 Lend. . .
12 Deals with adversity
```

Output:

```
nxd-12345678 Serial number of file
<ACROSS PUZZLE>
<TITLE>
Title of File
<AUTHOR>

<COPYRIGHT>

<SIZE>
15x15
<GRID>
<ACROSS>
___ fast
IRS-form experts
Lend...
Deals with adversity
```

Comment: Will the title always be on the second line?  Will ACROSS always appear on the third line?  The rest is straight-forward.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one's clued you in yet - sed is always the wrong tool for doing anything that spans multiple lines. You should be using awk.

Comment: Ed. No, no one did. I'm a front end dev, so I only have basic knowledge of things like this. My knowledge is mostly limited to things like PHP. I haven't had much use for command line skills. But I was able to get answered all the questions I had. This script I finally completed combines several different tasks into one script. Big time saver when preparing a bunch of files that, before this script, needed a lot of manual massaging of the data to make is ready for its final destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the title of the puzzle appears on the second line, and that the third line is always `ACROSS`, then there isn't any major problem:

```
sed -e '2,$s/^[0-9][0-9]* *//' \
    -e 's/\. \. \./.../g' \
    -e 's/___*/___/g' \
    -e '2i\
<ACROSS PUZZLE>\
<TITLE>' \
    -e '2a\
<AUTHOR>\
\
<COPYRIGHT>\
\
<SIZE>\
15x15\
<GRID>\
<ACROSS>' \
    -e '/^ACROSS$/d'
```

The first expression deals with numbers at the beginning of every line except the first, where the number seems to be retained, notwithstanding the claim that the code should 'Get rid of all numbers at beginning of line'.

The second line replaces ellipsis with spaces between the dots with ellipsis with no spaces between the dot.

The third line is one way to replace any sequence of two or more underscores with three underscores.

The third, fourth and fifth lines insert `<ACROSS PUZZLE>` and `<TITLE>` lines before the title line.

The sixth through fourteenth lines insert the other constant material into the file.

The last line of the script removes the `ACROSS` line of the data.

You could create little files and read those in appropriate places instead of using the insert and append operations.

```
sed -e '2,$s/^[0-9][0-9]* *//' \
    -e 's/\. \. \./.../g' \
    -e 's/___*/___/g' \
    -e '1r file.1' \
    -e '2r file.2' \
    -e '/^ACROSS$/d'
```

where `file.1` contains:

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE>
<TITLE>
```

and `file.2` contains:

```
<AUTHOR>

<COPYRIGHT>

<SIZE>
15x15
<GRID>
<ACROSS>
```

That is simpler to understand, but leaves you with a couple of intermediate files to remove, even if someone gets stroppy and hits the interrupt key.  That's easily managed, but outside the scope of the immediate question.

In combination with your other question, you can treat a `DOWN` line much the same as above.  Indeed, you could arrange to replace `ACROSS` with `<ACROSS>` and `DOWN` with `<DOWN>` quite easily.  If there are blank lines that are not wanted, you can remove them.  By ensuring that the entire line contains either `DOWN` or `ACROSS` (and nothing else), you can be reasonably safe from deviant clues to the crossword puzzles.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You are correct that you noticed about the serial number. However, I incorrectly specified the serial number. Really, each document's serial number starts with some letters. I apologize for only using pseudo-code in that part of my example. I should have been more accurate. The serial numbers all start with the letters "nxd". So the real serial number format is: "nxd-########"

Comment: OK; that simplifies life.  Simply drop the `2,$` from the first expression.  Or, indeed, leave it there — it does no harm since your first line won't start with numbers.  Be careful when asking questions.  People answering have only what you tell them to work with, so they work with that verbatim.

Comment: you dont need all those `-e`, just the first and rest is in the same string (with `;` or new line [better for human reading] as action separator)

Comment: They're not necessary for `sed` to understand it. They are IMNSHO necessary, or at the very least helpful, for the humans reading the script.